# Como remover resources não utilizados?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Existe alguma maneira ou extensão do Visual Studio que possibilite a procura dos resources não utilizados na aplicação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução que encontrei foi utilizar o [RESX Utils](https://resxutils.codeplex.com/).

Como essa solução não estava funcionando da forma adequada, poucas modificações no código fonte resolveram o problema.

**A solução aplicada:**

O RESX Utils utiliza apenas a chave do recurso como parâmetro de busca, então alterei pra utilizar dessa forma: `namespaceResx`.`nomeClasseResx`.`keyResx`;

Com isso, ele busca da forma correta em todos os arquivos selecionados como filtro na tela principal.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) da [Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com), porém o processo não é totalmente automatizado.

1- Acesse a classe Resources.Designer.cs
2- Dentro desta classe existirá uma property para cada recurso do seu projeto, basta clicar em cada uma com o botão direito e ir em "Find usages" ou "Find usages advanced"
3- Se não encontrar nenhuma referência, pode excluir o recurso.

Com este método você pode usar a pesquisa do próprio Visual Studio também, se não encontrar nenhum registro pode excluir o recurso.

Comment: Era desse trabalho exagerado que eu estava correndo. Como são vários arquivos de recurso, esse processo demoraria muito.